# BAD: [Python]Memory Error, Unable to allocate 696. MiB for an array with shape (9554, 9554) and data type float64

Tags: pycharm, out-of-memory

i use pycharm to create a matrix , the console said:
`MemoryError: Unable to allocate 696. MiB for an array with shape (9554, 9554) and data type float64` , and i set the VM Options to enlarge the VM memory , but it doesn't help . and my computer machine is 8GB , so is this the problem about pycharm or source code ? i  mean , i use libNMF , and the writer do not set dtype=float32.